# Open Street Map Route

Tags: openstreetmap

Problem Statement:

Step 1: Search for a location A
Step 2: Search for a location B
Step 3: Display the shortest routes
Step 4: Select a route
Step 5: Store the selected route

Please suggest me with a solution using OpenStreetMap on own server (ONLY India's data is sufficient)

Note: OSM setup on Ubuntu 12 already done, OSRM and OSRM-Web already setup But clueless how to continue further.

Answer (score 1):

- If step 1 and step 2 should support addresses and not just coordinates you will need a *geocoder*, for example [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).
- Pass these coordinates to OSRM, which will then calculate the shoretest route and display it (step 3).
- Not sure what step 4 is for, because you already have the shortest route.
- For step 5 it depends how you want to store your route. OSRM offers to export the route as GPX. If this is fine, you are done.